# Inform user to press escape key

Tags: input-fields, keyboard

We have a rich text editor that has become fairly complicated due to client requirements.

[image]

Because of this I have created the functionality of pressing the ESC key to exit the current element. Therefore if I am typing inside a `<p>`, pressing ESC will exit the paragraph and put the cursor immediately after it.

There is a visual cue at the bottom that mostly let's them know what elements they're currently in.

**How can I inform the user that they need to press ESC?**

**Or is there a button/icon that I could place in the toolbar that could signify such?**

Answer (score 7):

How about a tip next to the elements? This will help the users learn the keystroke.

[image: A tip next to the element may help the users]